# How to filter a variadic template pack by type derivation?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a template class receiving multiple types, each type received is subclass of one of two options.
I want to expand them differently depending the parent class identifying each of them. This is equivalent to implement "filter" over the variadic template parameters.

For example:

```
class A{};
class B{};

template<class... C>
struct F{
     std::tuple<types_derived_by<A, C>...> fn(types_subclassing<B, C>...){}
};
```

The types_derived_by template function should produce a variadic template pack with all the types in C that are derived from A, or B.

For example:

```
struct DA : public A{};
struct DB : public B{};
int main(){
    F<DA, DB> f;
    //f has a member function: DA fn(DB);

}
```

I'm using C++11, but I'm ok to move to c++14 if necessary.

Comment: What do you expect the return type to expand to? You can't return multiple types like that. Maybe you want a `std::tuple`?

Comment: Yes. Tuple. I mistyped

Comment: Maybe, you have to declare some `typedef ... NearestBase;` in your derived classes to iterate through superclasses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do something like:

```cpp
template <template <typename> class Pred, typename TUPLE, typename Res = std::tuple<>>
struct Filter;

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename Res> 
struct Filter<Pred, std::tuple<>, Res>
{
    using type = Res;
};

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename T, typename ... Ts, typename ... TRes> 
struct Filter<Pred, std::tuple<T, Ts...>, std::tuple<TRes...>> :
    Filter<Pred,
           std::tuple<Ts...>,
           std::conditional_t<Pred<T>::value,
                              std::tuple<TRes..., T>,
                              std::tuple<TRes...>>>
{
};
```

or alternatively, using [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat)

```cpp
template <template <typename> class Pred, typename TUPLE>
struct Filter;

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename ... Ts> 
struct Filter<Pred, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
           std::declval<std::conditional_t<Pred<Ts>::value,
                                           std::tuple<Ts>,
                                           std::tuple<>>>()...));
};
```

and then:

```cpp
class A {};
template <typename T>
using is_base_of_A = std::is_base_of<A, T>;

class B {};
struct DA : public A{};
struct DB : public B{};
struct DA1 : public A{};

static_assert(std::is_same<std::tuple<DA, DA1>,
                           Filter<is_base_of_A, std::tuple<DA, DB, DA1>>::type>::value,
              "unexpected");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39c14672dad83870) /
[Demo with `std::tuple_cat`](https://godbolt.org/z/1YqYPxYfM)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using tuples as return value and parameter this might be a solution for you:

```
template <typename Base, typename...T>
struct base_filter;

template <typename Base>
struct base_filter<Base>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template <typename Base, typename T1>
struct base_filter<Base, T1>
{
    using type = typename std::conditional_t<std::is_base_of<Base, T1>::value, std::tuple<T1>, std::tuple<>>;
};

template <typename Base, typename T1, typename...T>
struct base_filter<Base, T1, T...>
{
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(base_filter<Base, T1>::type(), base_filter<Base, T...>::type()));
};


//###########################################################

class A {};
class B {};


template<class...C>
struct F {
    typename base_filter<A, C...>::type fn(typename base_filter<B, C...>::type){}
};

struct DA : public A {};
struct DB : public B {};
struct DA1 : public A {};
struct DA2 : public A {};
struct DB1 : public B {};
struct DB2 : public B {};


int main() {
    std::tuple<DB> b;
    F<DA, DB> f1;
    std::tuple<DA> a = f1.fn(b);

    std::tuple<DB1, DB2> bb;
    F<DB1, DA1, DB2, DA2> f2;
    std::tuple<DA1, DA2> aa = f2.fn(bb);
}
```

Comment: `enable_if_else` looks like `std::conditional`

Comment: Because it does the same - I searched for something like `std::conditional` but didn't find anything. So I wrote my own version. I'll adjust my answer later.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Adjusted my code. Thanks for pointing it out.